# Epoch conversion not working as expected

Tags: python, time, epoch

Using the following code I want to convert the input date and time to epoch. The problem is I get an epoch output, but when I test it via conversion online (http://www.epochconverter.com/), the epoch does not translate to the date and time I input:

```
date_time2 = '09.03.1999' + " " + "13:44:17.000000"
pattern2 = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
epoch2 = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time2, pattern2)))
print epoch2
```

Comment: This works for me. What output are you getting from the online converter?

Comment: I get 921005057 when I run the block. However, when I put that timestamp in the online converter it says that timestamp is 18:44:17 GMT (note the input time is already GMT). It should say 13:44:17 GMT

Comment: Do you have to do something like this then?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527351/python-how-to-convert-a-timezone-aware-timestamp-to-utc-without-knowing-if-dst

Comment: Possibly. Even though the timestamp I'm feeding it is in GMT?

Comment: this might be a time zone issue?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here:

- `time.strptime` produces a `time.struct_time` which closely mirrors C's `tm` struct;
- The documentation of [`time.mktime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) is then fairly clear that it produces a **local time** from a `struct_time`, not a GMT time.

So instead you need a function that converts your `struct_time` into a GMT time.  Such a function is hidden away a bit in python, in the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) module.

Try instead:

```
date_time2 = '09.03.1999' + " " + "13:44:17.000000"
pattern2 = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'

# get a time structure
tm = time.strptime(date_time2, pattern2)

# convert to gmt
gmt_epoch = int(calendar.timegm(tm))
```

In this case we end up with:

```
>>> gmt_epoch
920987057
```

Plugging that into the website you've given produces that this is **GMT:** Tue, 09 Mar 1999 13:44:17 GMT

Comment: Thanks. What additional modules do I need to import for this to work? I'm getting  'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'tm_gmtoff' error when I run it. I'm already importing: `from datetime import datetime as dt,datetime,timedelta
import time
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
import pytz `

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 by the way

Comment: `tm_gmtoff` is available in Python 3.3 and greater: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time Please see my answer.

Comment: @user3498593 I've modified the answer so it should work on 2.7.  I tried to keep this answer strictly within the standard library ... but honestly, if you want to deal with times properly and easily you really should consider installing `pytz` as @bernie suggests

Answer (score 1):

(I already upvoted @donkopotamus' answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38558696/42346)

Using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19527596/42346 we can see how you can convert your local time to GMT. This requires [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

```
import datetime as dt 
import pytz

naive_date = dt.datetime.strptime('09.03.1999' + " " + "13:44:17.000000", 
                                  '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
localtz = pytz.timezone('Hongkong')
date_aware = localtz.localize(naive_date,is_dst=None)
utc_date = date_aware.astimezone(pytz.utc)
int(time.mktime(utc_date.utctimetuple()))
```

Result:

```
920987057
```

[image]